# Reduce side margin in Column chart of Microsoft Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am using Column chart in Microsoft Reporting in Visual Studio 2010. The chart axis take some margin at the start and end. There is an option to enable or disable this margin but nothing found to reduce it.
When i set false to the margin property of ChartAxis then chart starts from 0 point. But i want to give some space between y-axis and chart column.
Is there any way to reduce this side margin of Chart Axis?

[image]

As per MSDN, margin value cannot be modified so is there any patch to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you post a picture of your chart (perhaps to an [image hosting site](http://www.imgur.com)), to explain more clearly what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for reply, this is the image http://imgur.com/te0XEJ7